# How to use CSS to achieve the effect of text with borders while using only one label?

Tags: html, css

everyone, I have a question about CSS settings!
I hope there can be a black wire frame outside the text . The way I am currently trying is to use two tags and then use the positioning method to achieve an effect!

But I hope more You can use only one label and use CSS to achieve the same effect as a text frame, but I can’t find a way to achieve this effect using one label, so I would like to ask if there is a better way to achieve what I want What about the effect?

```css
body {
  background:yellow;
  font-family: Microsoft JhengHei,'微軟正黑體';
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  font-size:90px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
}

.border {
   -webkit-text-stroke-width: 4px;
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="border">hello</h1><h1 class="no-border">hello</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with the experimental `text-stroke: 2px red;` which seem to work only with the webkit prefix:

`-webkit-text-stroke: red;`
`-webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;`

https://caniuse.com/?search=text-stroke

Note that Firefox and Edge also respond to the -webkit flag, not -moz etc.

It should not be used because it's not standard, and is not on the track to become a standard feature either, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke-width) and Caniuse.

You could maybe use it with a pseudo element as a fallback. This should work with only one `h1` element, but the outline will never be very thick unless you add more shadows than the two I have added:

```css
    h1 {
      font-size:90px;
      color: black;
      position: absolute;
    }

    h1:after {
      content: 'hello';
      font-size: 90px;
      position: absolute;
      color: white;
      left: 0;
      text-shadow: 1px -1px 1px #000,
                   -1px 1px 1px #000;    
}
```

Comment: May I ask if I want to apply to all browsers, I originally used two tabs and then used the positioning method to achieve it! Would it be a better approach?

Comment: It's much safer yes, but it will create an SEO problem, because you suddenly have two h1 elements ("forbidden" according to the spec and Google). Screen readers for accessibility also won't know what to do and will probably read the same title twice unless you set one of them to aria-hidden. If SEO isn't a probem for you, then do it like you did.

Comment: Thanks for telling me all this

Comment: Np. I added a possible fallback idea where you can avoid using two h1 elements.